# gtag event is not firing in GA4 Debug View and also not showing in Network Tab Payload

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, bigcommerce, google-analytics-4, gtag.js

I am trying to implement the GA4 `view_item` Event in BigCommerce. The data is populating correctly in the source code but when I check that event in GA4 Debug View, it doesn't show this event.

I also checked the Network Tab payload in Chrome Dev Tools and that is also not showing any event.

Here's the output in the page source.

```
    <script>
gtag("event", "view_item", {
            currency: "USD",
            value: parseFloat(2.4),
            items: [                    {
                    item_id: "9781645072485",
                    item_name: "Alongside Jesus: Devotions for Teenagers",
                    currency: "USD",
                    discount: parseFloat(16.99),
                    item_brand: "Drew Hill",
                    price: parseFloat(2.4),
                    quantity: 1,
                    item_category:"Teen/Teen Books"
                }
            ]
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I presume you have the script and config code somewhere above the event? Another gtcha is that GA4 batches events so there can be a delay before you see it in the network tab. I often switch browser tabs to trigger the batch.

Comment: Can you check the console to see if there is any error?

Comment: @Darrellwan, I checked the console it's fine. Don't know what's happening here.

Comment: What about your gtag config code. Can you share the code about it and you can give us the G-xxx instead of the actual one?

Comment: <!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXXXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXXX');
</script>

Comment: @Darrellwan, I set up several other events such as begin_checkout, add_shipping_info, and purchase. All of these are firing correctly and showing data in GA4 reports.